# How can I send a post request with Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to send post request with Retrofit but server response an error 400: Bad Request.

BaseURL : http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com

This is a screenshot of server documentation.

[image: Server doc]

This is the Retrofit Interface.

```
package com.e.databaseapp

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface Service {
    @Headers("user: joan","Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET( "task" )
    fun getListTask() : Call<TaskListContainer>

    @Headers("user: joan","Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("task")
    fun saveTask (@Body task: Task) : Call<Task>

    @Headers("user: joan")
    @DELETE("task")
    fun deleteTask (task: String) : Call<Void>
}
```

I create an instance of Retrofit in my repository.

```
lass TaskRepository(val taskDao: TaskDao) {
    val gson : Gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    val loggingInterceptor : HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val httpClient : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build()

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()

    val service: Service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

...

}
```

This is the errot that I get when I try to post a task.

[image: Error 400: Bad Request]

Comment: add your base url or postman image

Comment: Please add the code, where you are creating the instance of the retrofit service and also the code, where you perform the actual call

Comment: Could you please update your question with the latest version of your code and a detailed description of your server endpoints and what's the error you are getting now?

Comment: @dglozano this is the latest version of my code

Comment: You didn't do what I said in my answer. You shouldnt be sending application/json, your server is expecting to get it in a FormUrlEncoded form. Delete the `@Body` annotation and include the annotation `@FormUrlEncoded` on top. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible you have on of these problems:

1) The server can't define the content of the response. 
Try to add the header with content type: `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")`

2) Your base url is missing `/` slash at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Base URLs should always end in /

Change `.baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com")` in

```
val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
```

to `.baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com/")`

Comment: The slash belongs to the base url in retrofit.

Comment: @DanielSpiess in his code i see this `.baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com")`

Comment: I don't think in the Retrofit Version of Today the slash is mandatory in both the base Url and the interface..

Comment: Yeah, and u added the slash to the Service. But i belongs to the base url. Sorry, but ur solition is wrong. https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html

Comment: @DanielSpiess yeah but base url should ent in `/`. I updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not a 100% sure if this is your problem, since the server documentation you have uploaded is not complete, I am pretty confident that the problem is that the server is asking you to send the data of the task to be created using the mime type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, that's why it says `formdata` to the right of the Create Task endopoint in the picture you uploaded with the server documentation.

However, you are using `@Body tasks: TaskListContainer`, which instead is sending the information of the new task(s) as JSON data `application/json`. [(@Body annotation)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body)

### This is what you are doing

I tested your endpoint with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) using `application/json` as the Content-Type of your request. This is what Retrofit is doing right now because you used the `@Body` annotation in the Retrofit service.

[image: Headers wrong]
[image: Response wrong]

### This is what you should do instead

Now, if I send a POST request with Postman but using the `form-data` type instead, with a Field with key `task` and a String value representing the name of the task to be created, I get a a successful response.

[image: Headers correct]
[image: Response correct]

To tell Retrofit to send the POST request like this, you have to define your `saveTask` method like this:

```
    interface Service {
    ...

    @Headers("user: joan")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("task")
    fun saveTask (@Field("task") taskname: String) : Call<Task>

    ...
}
```

You can see more information about @FormUrlEncoded annotation in [the official documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded).

Also, as @YuriPopiv said, you are missing a final slash in your `baseUrl`. Try to set it like this `.baseUrl("http://taskdemoserver.pythonanywhere.com/")` or define your endpoint starting with a leading `/`.

From [the docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#baseUrl-java.lang.String-):

> Base URLs should always end in /.
>   A trailing / ensures that endpoints values which are relative paths will correctly append themselves to a base which has path components.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Now the server response with 401 errror: Unathorized

Comment: Well, that's a whole new error. It's because the server is expecting you to be authenticated before being able to make requests to that endpoint. Each server has its own type of authentication method, and I don't know what is the one that your server is using. It can be a simple Basic Authentication, or it can be using a more advanced mechanism like JWT tokens. If you send me the details of your server, I might be able to help you. You can start taking a look at https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit

Comment: Not yet... Once the error 401 has been fixed, it gives me the error 400 again